# Как получит доступ к элементу в json python

Tags: python, json

есть json

```
    {'data': [{'account': '+380631191545',
           'comment': 'comment',
           'commission': {'amount': 0, 'currency': 643},
           'currencyRate': 1,
           'favoritePaymentEnabled': False,
           'personId': 380631195970,
           'total': {'amount': 1, 'currency': 643},
           'type': 'IN'}],
 'nextTxnDate': '2018-11-24T18:40:14+03:00',
 'nextTxnId': 14351924998}
```

Как вывести 'comment' и 'amount'??

Answer (score 0):

Это не json, а обычный словарь. Вывести с помощью базовых средств языка:

```
print(some_var['data'][0]['comment'])
```

Аналогично для `amount`.